# Case statement syntax

Tags: sql, oracle11g

The table I'm using has depreciation by fiscal year and accounting period.  I'm trying to have the depreciation amount go to 2 different columns based on the fiscal year and accoutning period.  I'm trying to do this with a nested case statement; which I'm sure is not correct since I'm getting the **ORA-00905 message**.  I'm relatively new to Oracle SQL and that is contribtuing to my issue as well.  Below is the code I have.  Any suggestions / corrections would be appreciated  Thanks for the help...

```
SELECT 
pdr.DEPTID as DEPTID, 
pdr.ASSET_ID as ASSET_NO,
pa.descr as DESCRIPTION,
pdr.ACCOUNT_AD as AD_ACCT, 
pdl.ACCOUNT as DE_ACCT,
pdr.DEPR as AMT_DEPR,
pdl.JOURNAL_ID as JRNL_ID,
pdl.JOURNAL_DATE as JRNL_DT,
pdr.FISCAL_YEAR as FY,
pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD as AP,

CASE 
  WHEN pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = 2014 THEN
    WHEN pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 11 THEN pdr.DEPR 
    END AS CURR_MONTH,

CASE  
  WHEN pdr.FISCAL_YEAR <> 2014  
    WHEN pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD <> 11 THEN pdr.DEPR 
    END AS PRIOR_MONTH

FROM PS_DEPR_RPT pdr

INNER JOIN PS_DIST_LN pdl 
ON pdl.BOOK = pdr.BOOK
AND pdl.BUSINESS_UNIT = pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT
AND pdl.FISCAL_YEAR = pdr.FISCAL_YEAR
AND pdl.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD
AND pdl.ASSET_ID = pdr.ASSET_ID
AND pdl.CF_SEQNO = pdr.CF_SEQNO

INNER JOIN PS_ASSET pa 
ON pa.ASSET_ID = pdl.ASSET_ID
AND pa.BUSINESS_UNIT = pdl.BUSINESS_UNIT

WHERE
pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT='A0465'
AND pdr.BOOK='PERFORM' 
AND ((pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = 2014 AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 11) OR (pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = 2014 AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = 10)) ;
```

Comment: this probably won't translate well in a comment, but it's unclear what your case statements are trying to convey.  your first "then" keyword has no "then" action, are you looking for an "and"?  what about your else?  If year is 2014 and month is 11 then use pdf.depr, what about if that is not the case use what then?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  The results pull 2 records for each asset - 1 for period 11 and 1 for period 10.  There is an amount on each row.  What I'm trying to do is put the amount for period 11 in 1 column and the amount for period 10 in a different column so I can display the results all on 1 row.  Thanks for your help....